# why can't I attach to my process?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, debugging

I can start debugging (F5).

If I start with Ctrl+F5 and then go to attach later I am unable.

The program name is grayed out. The attach button is disabled when I select the row for the program.

I've tried using Attach to "Automatic" or picking Managed 4.0 + Native.

I've tried checking both "Show processes from all users" and "Show processes in all sessions"

I'm running Visual Studio as an administrator.

Any ideas?

Comment: Define "unable."  What stops you?

Comment: The program name is grayed out.  The attach button is disabled when I select the row for the program.

Comment: Are you sure you are running in Debug mode and not Release mode?

Comment: Yes. I am running in Debug mode.

Comment: @rdkleine you don't need Debug mode in order to debug.

Answer (score 4):

You are probably seeing the .vshost.exe process for your application, which is always grayed out.

Look through the list of processes and make sure that there isn't another one listed with the same/similar name.

Also note: if this is a console application and the process reaches the end of the Main method (the console window will say "Press any key to continue . . ."), then you will probably not see the process listed, because it has ended.

Comment: I only see one instance of the application.  It is a Winforms application with native and managed code.  It is not a console application.  I'm still seeing the greyed out process, which is frustrating, because I am able to start the program in the debugger.  I just can't start the program and then attach to it later (which is convenient since mixed mode debugging can be painfully slow).

Comment: Hmm, ok.  Does the process that you see in the Available Processes list end with .vshost.exe?

Comment: @Derek - This is just a sanity check: instead of starting the application with the Ctrl+F5 key combination, go to the Debug menu and select "Start Without Debugging", then try to attach to the process.  Do you get the same behavior?  If it works, then maybe the problem is something weird, like maybe the Ctrl key on your keyboard doesn't work :)

Answer (score 0):

If you use the .vshost file for faster start times and you start without debugging you cannot attach because the .vshost process is always debugger bound to the Visual Studio instance.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding.   Are you talking about ProgramName.vshost.exe.config? Or actually running ProgramName.vshost.exe?  In the task manager I can see that I'm running ProgramName.exe.